# AWS Cognito does not work because of Expo SDK problem

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, expo, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I was working on my React Native project with AWS Amplify, everything went well
One day, I tried the AWS Cognito authentification feature I added few weeks ago, and it is not working anymore and I dont understand why. I searched for the error log all over the internet but nothing found.
Please help

When I call the Auth.signIn() method, I get the following error:
Expo managed workflow support for amazon-cognito-identity-js is only available in SDK 39 and higher.

Comment: it sounds like you updated the amazon-cognito-identity-js version in your project (perhaps by deleting node_modules and your lockfile) and now the latest version only supports SDK 39 and greater. you can try to find what version you used before and install that, or update to the latest Expo SDK version

Comment: thank you for your answer, but as I am working with amplify, (and i use the same amplify version as the beggining), I dont know where to change the version of aws cognito js in the package.json

Comment: you could use an older version of amplify, preferably the one you were using before. you can see what version you used before you had this issue by looking at your lockfile (package-lock.json or yarn.lock) from your last known working commit

Comment: i install the latest expo SDK version and it is working again. I had to go through many pb during the installation but now it's okay ! thank you for your help @brentvatne

Comment: @JosephHuang could you please tell the version for amplify, aws-sdk, expo, expo-cli (and all other related packages) that fixed the issued. I am having the same issue. Also, please write the answer so that one not need to read the comments to get the answer :)

Comment: @ShivamSingla yes i will, no matter your amplify or aws sdk version; you have to update you expo sdk to SDK 39 at least that's the point

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I went through many problem during installations but what made it for me was to install the latest version of expo (expo upgrade) (SDK 39 at least) and update all my package using a npm library:

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates
ncu
ncu -u
```